# Blazor: How to conditionally style an element

Tags: blazor, webassembly, blazor-webassembly

In Blazor i do want to style the input element with a condition. Here the code what I do use now, it works but later I faced a problem because here three different input elements are used.

```
@if (MyNumber > 100) 
    { <input type="number" @bind=MyNumber @bind:event="oninput" /> }
else if (MyNumber < 1)
    { <input type="number" @bind=MyNumber @bind:event="oninput" style="color:red" /> }
else
    { <input type="number" @bind=MyNumber @bind:event="oninput" style="background:lightgreen" /> }
```

Is there a better possibility to set the style with a condition?

**Edit:**
Thanks for the answers, there are definately several solutions possible. I even found another one using the attributes:

```
<input type="number" @bind=MyNumber @bind:event="oninput" @attributes="SetStyle(MyNumber)" />
@code{
public Dictionary<string, object> SetStyle(int myNumber)
{
    var dict = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    if (myNumber > 100) { }
    else if (myNumber < 1) dict.Add("style", "color:red");
    else dict.Add("style", "background:lightgreen");
    return dict;
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are many ways to do it, I would use:

```
<input style="@StyleForNumber(MyNumber)" type="number" @bind=MyNumber @bind:event="oninput" />
```

...

```
private string StyleForNumber(int n)
{
   if (n > 100) return "";
   if (n < 1)  return "color:red";
   return "background:lightgreen";
}
```

the function can be re-used and easily maintained.

I would  probably use Css classes instead of direct styles though.

Comment: I see some habit here.  I normally make class strings rather than direct styling also. :D

Comment: Also, I think you need to call the method: `<input style="@StyleForNumber()" type="number" @bind=MyNumber @bind:event="oninput" />`  But I think your answer is more elegant than mine.

Comment: Yes, the `()` are needed, they just got lost  in copy/paste.

Comment: This is the correct answer, but I propose a solution that makes this easier. https://www.nuget.org/packages/BlazorComponentUtilities/

Comment: You've done some very nice work there, Ed.  However, I think the OP's main goal is to learn about how Blazor works, not to solve his enterprise-level CSS needs.  :)  (I'll upvote your comment anyway, though, because who doesn't want to play with new toys?)

Answer (score 0):

You can put variables almost anywhere in your markup, very much including style or class attributes:

```
@{
    string StyleString;
    if (MyNumber < 1) StyleString = "color:red";
    else if (MyNumber > 100) StyleString = "";
    else StyleString = "background: lightgreen";
}    
    <input type="number" @bind=MyNumber @bind:event="oninput" style="@StyleString" />

@code {
    int MyNumber { get; set; }
}
```